# How to write method that has argument implementing an interface in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, interface

I have an interface called `ListInterface<T>` that has the method `join`:

```
public interface ListInterface<T> {
     /**
     * Join a new list to the original list.
     * @param otherList The new list to be joined.
     * @return Original list with appended part from the new list.   
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException.
     */
     public ListInterface<T> join(ListInterface<T> otherList) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

Two classes `DoubleLinkedList` and `MyArrayList` implement this interface. 
So in `DoubleLinkedList`, I need to write `join` like this:

```
public ListInterface<T> join(DoubleLinkedList<T> otherList) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    (...)
}
```

And in `MyArrayList`:

```
public ListInterface<T> join(MyArrayList<T> otherList) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    (...)
}
```

But this is not possible and the type of arguments must be `ListInterface<T>`. If I change the method signatures in these classes to `public ListInterface<T> join(ListInterface<T> otherList)`, then I can't use other specific methods on `DoubleLinkedList` or `MyArrayList` anymore. How should I change the method signature in `ListInterface` in order to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I change the method signature in `ListInterface` in order to fix this?

You don't. `ListInterface`'s method signature is correct as is.

> If I change the method signatures in these classes to `public ListInterface<T> join(ListInterface<T> otherList)`, then I can't use other specific methods on `DoubleLinkedList` or `MyArrayList` anymore.

That is correct. You should not be using any subclass methods because `otherList` may not be the same type of list as `this`. The user might try to join a `DoubleLinkedList` to a `MyArrayList`, yes?

Use the interface methods only.